# One string PHP Content Type and HTML in Message fields

Tags: content-type, php

I am trying to add an image into my body for a php email. However I am having difficulty adding in the content type and making this work. Is it because I am refusing to have multiple $header = and $header .= lines?

Can't you add all of this code into one line of php script with . "\r\n" .

?

$emailthisbody = ' \n\n Message Line 1. \n\n Name: $emailthisname \n\nEmail: $emailthisemail \n\nProperty: $emailthiscomments ';

$header = 'From: '.$sitename.' <'.$emailTo1.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is your actual code:

```
$header = 'From: '.$sitename.' <'.$emailTo1.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';
```

Then I might see your problem. You have a literal backslash r backslash n in 2 places. Try this,

```
$header = 'From: '.$sitename.' <'.$emailTo1.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'."\r\n";
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Perfect, this worked great. I have updated the code with the final working code. I removed the \n\n out of the html code and replaced with <br>.
$emailthisbody = '<html><head></head><img src="image.jpg" alt="alt tag" /> <br><br>Name: $emailthisname <br><br>Email: $emailthisemail <br><br>Property: $emailthiscomments </html>';


$emailthisheaders = 'From: '.$blogname.' <'.$emailTo1.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'."\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

I find the php mail function to be a bit clunky in that you really have to know how to format a raw email.

I highly recommend using the [PHPMailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for sending anything other than the simplest of emails. Another popular mailing library would be [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Both will allow you to do what you are attempting in a much simpler way and you should be able to find plenty of documentation and tutorials online as they are both fairly widely adopted.